# how to create list with all possible combinations

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have the following table:

```
a b c d ...
q w e r ...
z x   v ...
  p
```

I am having lots of trouble finding an algorithm (preferably VBA but the thinking is almost the same in other languages) that will generate a list with all combinations - besides the fact that I only have a few rows, there are a lots of columns and this would not be accurate if done manual, I trust VBA to make it 100% complete.

so, the output should be a list like this:

```
a
a,q
a,z
q,z
z
a/b
a/b,w
a/b,x
a/b,p
a/b,w,x
a/b,w,p
a/b,x,p
a/w
a/w,x
a/w,p
a/x
a/x,p
a/p
a,q/b
a,q/b,w
a,q/b,x
a,q/b,p
a,q/b,w,x
a,q/b,w,p
a,q/b,x,p
a,q/w
a,q/w,x
a,q/w,p
a,q/x
a,q/x,p
a,q/p
....etc.
```

- I do not really care about the "/" and "," signs, I will find a way to put them right ("/" is between elements of separate columns while "," is between the elements from the same column)
- the combinations are made two ways - horizontally and vertically with the following restriction: can only combine 'n-1' elements (horizontally and/or vertically)

Comment: New members commonly mistake this for a service site where we will do the work. It is a Q&A community where specific questions are asked after you have attempted something and get stuck. Please add details of what you have tried so far, including scripts, code or formulas, and we will try to help. If you need more info about asking questions, check out ***[ask]*** in the ***[help]***.

Comment: Your example has missing data points as well as additional rows (second column has an additional row). Normalize for number of rows and it might be easier to come up with a solution. If possible fill gaps. Might as easy as running number of rows loops. What data structure does your data reside in?

Comment: Do you want **combinations** or **permutations**, that is, should both *a,q* and *q,a* appear in the list ??

Comment: @CharlieRB - this is my question - it is not mandatory to get the full working code & no, I can not share any previous attempts since I can not figure out the algorithm

Comment: @Gary'sStudent - I am not interested in both variations, just 'a,q' will do just fine

Comment: @Seth - think this way: you have one list that you need to do all possible combinations except the one with all the items. now let's suppose that each element of that list becomes a list of it's own and for each of it's elements (that now = list) you must do all possible combinations except the one with all the items.

Comment: EDIT: let's forget the part 'except all the items', we can trim that down afterwords, I can not figure out how to compile both directions ...

Comment: @LaurentiuMirica - "Let's forget the part 'except all the items" instead of a comment you should edit the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example indicated **12** items.  This code *(supplied by John Coleman in 2005)* will list the 4095 permutations of the list in column **B**.  There are 2<sup>N</sup>-1 items:

```
Sub MAIN()
    B = Array("a", "b", "c", "d", "q", "w", "e", "r", "z", "x", "v", "p")
    Call GrayCode(B)
End Sub

Function GrayCode(Items As Variant) As String
    Dim CodeVector() As Integer
    Dim i, kk As Integer
    Dim lower As Integer, upper As Integer
    Dim SubList As String
    Dim NewSub As String
    Dim done As Boolean
    Dim OddStep As Boolean

    kk = 1
    OddStep = True
    lower = LBound(Items)
    upper = UBound(Items)

    ReDim CodeVector(lower To upper) 'it starts all 0
    Do Until done
        'Add a new subset according to current contents
        'of CodeVector

        NewSub = ""
        For i = lower To upper
            If CodeVector(i) = 1 Then
                If NewSub = "" Then
                    NewSub = "," & Items(i)
                Else
                    NewSub = NewSub & "," & Items(i)
                End If
            End If
        Next i
        If NewSub = "" Then NewSub = "{}" 'empty set
        SubList = SubList & vbCrLf & NewSub
        Cells(kk, 2) = Mid(NewSub, 2)
        kk = kk + 1
        'now update code vector
        If OddStep Then
            'just flip first bit
            CodeVector(lower) = 1 - CodeVector(lower)
        Else
            'first locate first 1
            i = lower
            Do While CodeVector(i) <> 1
                i = i + 1
            Loop
            'done if i = upper:
            If i = upper Then
                done = True
            Else
                'if not done then flip the *next* bit:
                i = i + 1
                CodeVector(i) = 1 - CodeVector(i)
            End If
        End If
        OddStep = Not OddStep 'toggles between even and odd steps
    Loop
    GrayCode = SubList
End Function
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[John Coleman Code](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/microsoft.public.excel.programming/%22John$20Coleman%22/microsoft.public.excel.programming/4C_yJDWDvlk/hfaq4p1SH3kJ)

You can change/add/remove items by changing the `Array()`.  Too many will overflow the limits to the number of items in a colummn.

Comment: thank you very much for your help !
while this is not my solution to my problem, it's answering one big question that makes a huge difference to how I must approach the subject at hand.

this is very good work !